# ngstrap typeahead unordered multiple keyword search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I having an issue with ngstrap typeahead with the scenario below:

```
var companyItem= [
 {
"item_id": 1,
"item_name": "mobile phone middle nokia",
"company_id": 1,

},
{
"item_id": 2,
"item_name": "mobile phone iphone",
"company_id": 1,

},
{
"item_id": 8,
"item_name": "mobile phone samsung",
"company_id": 1,

},
{
"item_id": 9,
"item_name": "apple watch",
"company_id": 1,

}
]
```

My Markup :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemName" id="itemName" ng-model="item.itemName" data-min-length="0" bs-options="item as item.item_name for item in companyItem | filter:{item_name:$viewValue}:customCompare" bs-typeahead="setCustomerData" data-watch-options="true" data-container="body" autocomplete="off" ng-readonly="readOnly" required>
```

and my scripts is :

```
$scope.customCompare = function(itemName, viewValue) {
    var keyword = viewValue.split(" ");
    var partialMatch = false;

    for(var i=0;i<keyword.length;i++){
          console.log('keyword'+i+' '+keyword[i]);
            console.log('itemName '+itemName);
            console.log('keyword[i].indexOf(itemName) > -1 '+itemName.indexOf(keyword[i].toString()));
            if(itemName.indexOf(keyword[i].toString()) > -1){
               console.log(' <<>>---------------');
                partialMatch =true;

            }       

    }
       return partialMatch;
}
```

I've try to search with keyword 'mobile iphone' in the input text but there're no result.

This return true as I'm write in the console log but the record not showing

Anyway if 'phone iphone' it's working like default typeahead

Anything I'm done wrong or this approach is not working

https://plnkr.co/edit/3iJwREetLMnTup24Sbtd

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you include the console log when typing 'mobile iphone' and when typing 'phone iphone'? Also, if you can build a plunker like http://plnkr.co/edit/dvmVTZwzjMCHrNUhWkKU?p=preview, it would be helpful.

Comment: Hello Tanin here's the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/3iJwREetLMnTup24Sbtd f I'm type 'phone iphone' it's working as default typeahead. Anyway 'mobile iphone' it's not working I got another solution for async via api   to back-end but if any solution for not hit too much database would be appreciate, Thanks

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ng-strap adds a default filter that uses a default comparator](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/9a29385e7e39941120b3fcb5dcefb85b0d7ef37b/dist/angular-strap.js#L164) after your `item as item.item_name for item in companyItem | filter:{item_name:$viewValue}:customCompare`.

One hacky solution is to bypass the default filter.

```js
$scope.alwaysTrue = function() { return true; }
```

```html
<input ... bs-options="item as item.item_name for item in companyItem | filter:{item_name:$viewValue}:customCompare" data-comparator="alwaysTrue" ...>
```

A cleaner solution would be to set `data-comparator="customCompare"`. Sadly, that doesn't work because [here](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/9a29385e7e39941120b3fcb5dcefb85b0d7ef37b/dist/angular-strap.js#L164) contains `:$viewValue`, not `:{item_name: $viewValue}`. So, `customCompare` never gets to process a whole object.

The API can and should be improved, and you should open an issue about it on github.

Comment: How about I'm set data-comparator=true? I've tried but it's not working

Comment: You can try, but I think it might not work because it expects a function, and `true` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

I got another solution as I saw "filter: 'bsAsyncFilter'" in typeahead.js so I override in my js by bypass the filter because now I'm using async data through api :

```
function CustomTypeaheadFilter ($filter)  {
return function(array, expression, comparator) {

  if(array && angular.isFunction(array.then)) {
    return array.then(function(results) {
        console.log(results);
     // return $filter('filter')(results, expression, comparator)
     return results;
    });
  } else {
    //return $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator);
    return array;
  }
}
};
```

Mark up:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemName" id="itemName" ng-model="item.itemName" data-min-length="0" bs-options="item as item.item_name for item in getItemfromDB($viewValue)" bs-typeahead="setCustomerData" data-filter="CustomTypeaheadFilter" autocomplete="off"  required>
```

filter option is not declare in ngstrap document, I'm posted the issue on the github anyway hope ngstrap will raise this option to the document then.

Comment: Yes, setting data-filter to be your own filter works too. You can pretty much make it to do anything you would like to.